# Highlight Field in Views

Tags: views

I just created a Views table with a few columns. I would like to create a rule that enables Views to highlight certain fields if information is missing/blank. What would be the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your view's settings, click on the field that might be empty and open up `NO RESULTS BEHAVIOUR`. Uncheck everything in the dropdown (perhaps leave `Count the number 0 as empty` depending on your use case) then add text like this in the `No results text`

```
<div class="empty"></div>
```

Comment: Nothing happened. I added .empty class as background-color: #000000; and the cells did not turn black.

Comment: Propably a CSS issue. Try this for a start: .empty {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the browser dev console (inspect element). If the class is in there it is a style issue, else a views issue.